# How to fix.. Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum AVCaptureTorchMode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a older mac and just got a new one. I'm trying to release my apps to apple. I wrote the app on on Xcode 4.3 on my old mac and now I want to use Xcode 5.1 to release it to apple now. I'm getting this error here:

> Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum AVCaptureTorchMode' to... I'm not sure what the rest of it means.

So my question is, what does this error mean and why does it occur it the code should be backwards comparable. I usually on write code in java/android so I'm not really that experienced as I should be with objective c. How could I go about resolving this issue?

```
- (void) strobeON{    

onButton.hidden = YES;
offButton.hidden = NO;

onView.hidden = NO;
offView.hidden = YES;

AVCaptureDevice *flashlight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
if([flashlight isTorchAvailable] && [flashlight isTorchModeSupported: AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
{

    BOOL success = [flashlight lockForConfiguration:nil];
    if (success)
    {
        [flashlight setFlashMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
        [flashlight unlockForConfiguration];    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`AVCaptureDevice`'s flashMode property takes an `AVCaptureFlashMode` enum rather than an `AVCaptureTorchMode` enum.

Change this line:

```
[flashlight setFlashMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
```

to this:

```
[flashlight setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn]
```